# Removing Visual Studio Code current code block highlight

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how to turn off the current code block highlighting, it only highlights the block of code you are currently editing. In the picture its the fun yellow line. I think it was added in 1.22.2

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS Code insiders 1.23.0-insider and I can *not* replicate your code highlighting. Maybe it's some plugin that does this? Have you tried disabling all of your extensions and see if it persists?

Comment: Your a legend! It was not surprisingly 'Bracket Pair Colorizer' extension. I swear it wasn't working like that before I upgraded, who knows. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a feature of Bracket Pair Colorizer plugin that I think you're using. See the plugin's marketplace page for settings guide.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was driving me bonkers.